# Possessive case question

Tags: possessives

On one hand, possessive case is one of the simplest topics and still there are few nuisances. Should I say:

> Tom, professor assistant, was entering the lab.

or

> Tom, professor's assistant, was entering the lab.

Tom doesn't belong to professor, but words *professor* and *assistant* definitely have the possessive link - `assistant OF the professor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, Tom does not belong to professor but the professor can still say, *"He is **my** assistant"*, can't he?

That said, *"Whose assistant? ~ Professor's"*. The possessive is fine there.

Out of those two,

> Tom, (the) professor's assistant, was entering the lab.

is okay.

Comment: Why did you put *the* article before *professor's assistant*?

Comment: Because we are talking about Tom and his *specified* post. Compare - *Denis, the principal, entered Xavier's college and students clapped*

Answer (score 2):

**Tom, the professor's TA, entered the room.** is how it would be said in American English.  Substitute "assistant" for "TA" (teaching assistant).